# Keeping authentication state between Firebase - WebApp (.NET Core MVC)

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, asp.net-core-mvc

I am creating an **ASP.NET Core MVC** app, where the authentication provider will be FireBase.

My Web App is hosted in Azure and, once user signs in, it sends an HTTPS request to my firebase endpoint, which looks like `https://myFirebaseApp.cloudfunctions.net/signup` with username and password, and it will create a user as below;

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start?authuser=0

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // ...
});
```

My intention is to get a kind of `session token` in the response and save it in a cookie. And everytime user navigates to another page, I will need to validate that cookie/token to keep authentication persistent.

What would be the way to achieve this? Or is there any better practice to keep this integration?

Comment: You may be look for a session cookie instead of a token, to reduce the refresh requirements. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies But aside from that: what problem are you worried about with this approach?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for your response. Is see createUser method returns accessToken and refreshToken. Would it be a good practice for me to save this token in the cookie and keep state with this? If not, after I generate cookie and send back to WebApp, what difference it will make to keep state? Both ways, wouldn't I send token or generated cookie back to firebase?

Comment: I've never used session cookies myself, but they sound made for this scenario.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I was thinking to use generated accessToken for both WebApp and Mobile Apps with similar implementation logic. I will look more into doc reference you sent to verify its usage vs accessToken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out I can use custom tokens for this. What I need to use is `createCustomToken` and 
`signInWithCustomToken` methods.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens

Create Token:

```
  createCustomToken(request, response) {
    let uid = request.query.uid;
    if (!uid) {
      response.send("query.uid is required.");
      return;
    }
    let additionalClaims = {
      myExtraField: 1
    };
    this.admin
      .auth()
      .createCustomToken(uid, additionalClaims)
      .then(function(customToken) {
        // Send token back to client
        response.send(customToken);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        response.send(error);
      });
  }
```

Sign-in:

```
  signInWithCustomToken(request, response) {
    const id_token = request.query.id_token;
    if (!id_token) {
      response.send("query.id_token is required.");
      return;
    }

    // Sign in with signInWithCustomToken.
    this.authService
      .signInWithCustomToken(id_token)
      .then(result => {
        response.send(result);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        response.send(error);
      });
  }
```